# ng-invalid in angular input just when submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a interesting problem to solve, but I don't know how, 
I have a dynamically inputs in my view, and the inputs in Angular are validated in realtime, but I don't want that, the angular inputs in input class "ng-invalid" and I want to add "ng-invalid" just when submit my form:

```
<div ng-if="conditionItem.field.id"
     ng-class="{'error': FieldConditionsCtrl.feedback.type === 'error'}"
     dynamic
     input-router << Here is my how generates the inputs
     source="conditionItem.field"
     ng-model="conditionItem.situation[$index]">
</div>
```

When I modify the generated input, AngularJS inputs in my input class the following classes "ng-invalid ng-empty":

[image]

I want to add this classes just when submit to make the border red.
Any help for this issue?

Comment: You should not post code as an image because: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5535245

Comment: He was just showing inside chrome developer tools. That is not an image of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used the [$submitted](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$submitted) property of the ngFormController to qualify the setting of the `error` class.

```
ng-class="{error: form1.$submitted && form1.field1.$invalid}"
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#binding-to-form-and-control-state)